# How to use fingerprint to decrypt a folder encrypted with ecryptfs?

Tags: fingerprint

I want to decrypt a  folder encrypted with ecryptfs with fingerprint recognition on Lenovo Thinkpad.

Example:

```
# service fprintd start
# mount -t ecryptfs [custom options] folder folder
Swipe your finger across the fingerprint reader
#
```

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts